# Improving order of operations and testing if a value has a decimal

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm trying to create a program that prints out pentagonal numbers up to n = 100. A pentagonal number is defined as n(3n-1)/2 for n = 1, 2, 3 so the first pentagonal numbers would be 1, 5, 12, 22..etc

```
package mathematical.functions.test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MathematicalFunctionsTest {
    public static int getPentagonalNumber(int n) {
        int i = 0;
        double part_one = (3 * n) - 1;
        double part_two = part_one / 2;
        while (i < 100){
            if (part_two == int(part_two))
            {
                System.out.println(n);
                i++;
            }
            else{                
        } 
    }
}
```

This is just part of my program above. I have two problems right now:

1. I do not know how to properly implement order of operations. What I have done is break up the operation n(3n - 1)/2 into part_one and part_two. Is this good practice?
2. Looking at the nested if in the while loop, I am trying to test if `part_two` is an integer (i.e. has no decimal). I've tried many things but Java is not letting me including the `%` operator.

Comment: use the remainder operator instead of division and check if it returns zero or not, if it does the number is pentagonal. i.e. `if (n*(3*n -1) %2 ) == 0){ System.out.println(n)}`. You might not need else, since you do not want to print numbers other than pentagonal numbers

Comment: You can use `someDoubleOrFloat % 1 == 0` to test if something has no decimals.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark one of the answers as 'accepted' in order to help future users who have a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing part of your equation (factor of n). You can combine them into one statement like so:

```
double num = n * (3 * n - 1) / 2
```

Just use brackets the way you normally would. Java understands proper order of operations.

Try the following to check if the number is an int:

```
if ((num == Math.floor(num)) && !Double.isInfinite(num)) {
  // integral type
}
```

This works by flooring (truncating the decimal) the number and checking to see if it's the same as the original number. It also has the added check to ensure that the number is finite.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how to properly implement order of operations. What I have done is break up the operation n(3n - 1)/2 into part_one and part_two. Is this good practice?

Yes, it is okay to do it like that. Alternatively, you can use a `()` and do it as follows:

```
double part_one = n * (3 * n - 1) / 2;
```

> Looking at the nested if in the while loop, I am trying to test if part_two is an integer (i.e. has no decimal). I've tried many things but Java is not letting me. I tried using the % operator, too. But it did not let me aswell.

I do not know the use case but if you want to see whether it is parse-able to Integer then you can do something like this:

```
while (i < 100){
    String str = String.valueOf(part_two);
    int conv = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("."))));  
    if(part_two - conv == 0) {
        /* Yes */
    } else {
        /* No */
    }           
}
```

Comment: The calculation is still off by a factor of ```n```.

Comment: @docksteaderluke Just noticed that. Thanks for highlighting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said the syntax for your equation isn't difficult. `n(3n-1)/2` would turn into `n * (3*n - 1) / 2` although if you want a correct double out of this you want to make one of the numbers into a double otherwise every answer will be become an integer `n * (3.0*n - 1) / 2.0`.

You were correct on detecting if a double is an integer except for the syntax.

```
public static boolean isInteger(double d) {
    return d == (int) d;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double num = i * (3.0*i- 1) / 2.0;
        if(isInteger(num)) System.out.println("("+i+", "+num+")");
    }
    /* Result:
    (1, 1.0)
    (2, 5.0)
    (3, 12.0)
    (4, 22.0)
    (5, 35.0)
    (6, 51.0)
    (7, 70.0)
    (8, 92.0)
    (9, 117.0)
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you will use it for real big numbers,  much bigger than 100, I suggest that part one will be `n/2` and part two will `3*n - 1`,  in order to avoid overflows.